# uninitialized constant Rake::DSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I met the problem 'uninitialized constant Rake::DSL'.
I have tried to add gem 'rake','0.8.7' in the Gemfile, but it didn't work out. Are there any other way to fix the problem? Thank you!

```
n177-p118:testapp shuang$ rake db:migrate --trace
(in /Users/shuang/rails/testapp)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:11
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:289:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:289:in `initialize_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `instance_exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `load_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `load_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:424:in `load_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/shuang/rails/testapp/rakefile:8
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:31
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably horribly bad form, but adding this to the top of my Rakefile worked for me:

```
module Rake
  module DSL
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your gemfile.lock, it must be having a version of rake which is > 0.8.7. If yes then delete all then delete all the instance of the version or delete all the content of gemfile.lock and then do bundle install again.

Comment: I have this problem too, and under railties it shows rake (>= 0.8.7)

Answer (score -1):

You can also try to run

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```